# GCP Cloud Builds sporadically fail with error "Internal Error" (status = INTERNAL_ERROR)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KUCO.png)

No other errors are in available, and the build does not even start a log. Sifting through logs explorer with no filter also doesn't yield a smoking gun.

Retrying the build normally fixes it, although it can happen 2-3 times subsequently.

Any ideas of how to investigate this issue? Or common causes of this phenomenon?

Couple interesting things about the build:

- It's a GitHub repo which hosts the code and cloudbuild.yaml
- It is run in a private pool. The private pool's network is peered with a private GKE cluster network via VPN tunnel, as the build does some K8 deployment.

Tried going through all other logs.